# NSData object empty for unknown reason (saving image)

Tags: ios, image, file, save, nsdata

Okay so here is what i'm doing :

1. Loading imageView (with image), and letting the user chose to add filters.

2a. If he doesn't do anything and just saves the picture, the picture saves.

2b. If he uses any filter, the image view updates to the filtered picture, and then use the same method to save.

**My problem : When the image has been filtered, the NSData object that stores it for the photo to be saved is nil.**

Notes :

- Both pictures are saved using the same methods.
- I'm using CIColorControls to modify the picture.
- When the user filters the photo, then resets the photo to its
  original state, it saves.

Code :

*viewdidLoad :*

```
    self.imgPicture.image = _photo;   //setting the picture taken from camera in imageView
    _tempPhoto = [_photo copy];       //storing it so it can be reset
```

*Saving file (image in the view):*

```
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
     NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
     [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm"];
     NSString *imageName = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [NSError *err = nil;
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imgPicture.image, 0.3) writeToFile:[basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName] 
                                                               options:NSDataWritingAtomic 
                                                                 error:&err];
```

*One of the filter methods :*

```
- (IBAction)softFilter:(id)sender {

    _photo = [self filterImageWithBrightness:-0.15 AndContrast:0.95];
    [self.imgPicture setImage:_photo];
   }
```

The error always logs (null).
I'm all out of ideas, i've been on this for 3 days and for the life of me, i can't figure out what's wrong. On top of that, i know that it's probably something incredibly stupid. But any answer/comment is welcome :)

Comment: Maybe you have to initialize somewhere _photo.If i understood the result of filterImageWithBrightness is always nill.Right?

Comment: No, that's the thing. The filtered picture displays correctly (so i'm guessing its not nil...). It's really just the UIIMageJPEGRepresentation that is nil when I save the image. But ONLY when its the filtered version of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep your modified image you could use :

```
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:@{kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer : @(YES)}];

CIImage *filteredImageData = [filter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:filteredImageData fromRect:[filteredImageData extent]];
UIImage *filteredImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage scale:[_photo scale] orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

Answer (score 0):

Zil here is a method that works fine for me to save photos.

```
-(void) saveImage:(UIImage *)image withFileName:(NSString *)imageName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {
if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
    NSString *lala=[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"png"]];


    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"png"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];

    [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:lala]];


} else if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || [[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpeg"]) {

    NSString *lala=[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"jpg"]];


    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"jpg"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];

    [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:lala]];

}
}
```

The only difference is the NSAtomicWrite parameter.

Maybe it could help you.

Comment: It's pretty much the same code as mine except you do tests for the file name and got everything in a saving method. 
I tried it but with no avail. :(
Same problem, normal pictures are saved, filtered pictures aren't